# A failing check-constraint with hibernate causes all subsequent operation to fail

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Say I have a table which looks like this

```
Create table User
(
  ID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  Name nvarchar(50),
  Gender char(1) check(Gender in ('M','F'))
)
```

a entity class generated from the table by hibernate

```
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    ····omit the getters,setters and constuctor··
    }
```

and a method save a user entity to the database like this

```
public void saveUser(User u)
{
   try{
     Session.save(u);
   }
   ····omit other parts····
}
```

If I call the `saveUser` method with a user that has an invalid gender field (`user.getGender=="Femail"`) ,the method fails with a `hibernate  "Data too long for column gender"` exception. So far so good. The problem is that if I call the method again with a user that has a valid gender field(`user.getGender=="F"`) ,the `hibernate  "Data too long for column gender"` still pops up.

It's only after I restart the application that the method will success.

MySQL5.7+Hibernate4.0.4 with JDBC connection

TL;DR
A failing check-constraint with hibernate causes all subsequent operation to fail,the only fix is restart the application

Comment: I would suspect this has something to do with how your application manages transactions, because this is absolutely not expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use character rather than using String in java. For better readability you can use enumeration and integers to represent this kind of data types.